# asp.net DropDownList задать стиль при наведении?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

```
                    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="BaseItem">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="32 66 1.5">Сабля драгуна (32 - 66 / 1.50)</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="31 72 1.4">Рапира гарпии (31 - 72 / 1.40)</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
```

У меня есть такой блок кода. В результате он выглядит вот так: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня не получается сменить стиль при наведении наListItem (синие выделение). Как это можно сделать?

Comment: на css это делается так выбираете элемент например asp:ListItem   и добавляете hover получится так asp:ListItem:hover{тут пишите свой код на css }

Comment: для css нету asp:ListItem

Comment: @Andreyтогда если быть точным то для html